# Select Max value comparing two rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in the format below:

```
+--------+------------+---------+-------+
| Entity | Department | Product | Value |
+--------+------------+---------+-------+
| E1     | D1         | P1      |    10 |
| E1     | D1         | P2      |    20 |
| E1     | D1         | P3      |    70 |
| E2     | D2         | P1      |    40 |
| E2     | D2         | P2      |    50 |
| E2     | D2         | P3      |    60 |
+--------+------------+---------+-------+
```

Group By each Entity and Department I want to,

- Select the product which (has the highest value) AND (the highest value is at least double of the second highest value).
- If true, return the Product and the highest Value.
- If false, return all the Products and their Values.

Intermediate result:

```
+--------+------------+---------+-------+
| Entity | Department | Product | Value |
+--------+------------+---------+-------+
| E1     | D1         | P3      |    70 |
| E1     | D1         | P2      |    20 |
| E1     | D1         | P1      |    10 |
| E2     | D2         | P3      |    60 |
| E2     | D2         | P2      |    50 |
| E2     | D2         | P1      |    40 |
+--------+------------+---------+-------+
```

Final result:

```
+--------+------------+---------+-------+
| Entity | Department | Product | Value |
+--------+------------+---------+-------+
| E1     | D1         | P3      |    70 |
| E2     | D2         | P1      |    40 |
| E2     | D2         | P2      |    50 |
| E2     | D2         | P3      |    60 |
+--------+------------+---------+-------+
```

Not sure if this is achievable solely through SQL. Please let me know for any solution.

Comment: Which RDBMS -- you tagged 2?

Comment: what attempts have you made? any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach for `sql server`:

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by entity, dept order by value desc) rn,
    max(value) over (partition by entity, dept) topvalue
  from yourtable
  ) 
select entity, dept, product, value
from cte c
where exists (
  select 1
  from cte c2
  where c.rn = 1 
    or (c.dept = c2.dept 
    and c.entity = c2.entity 
    and c2.rn = 2
    and 1.0*c2.topvalue/c2.value <= 2)
)
order by entity, dept, product
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7487/4)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `row_number` .

first cte sorts the entries with in a entity based on value

second cte checks for all values where condition ( highest value > 2 * second highest value) is met

third select gets rows from cte and all other entities where conditions are not met

```
with cte 
as
(
select row_number() over ( partition by entity order by value desc) as rn,
   entity, department, product, value
from Table1
)
, cte1
as
(
select c1.Entity, C1.department, C1.product, c1.value from 
cte c1
join cte c2
on c1.rn =1
and c2.rn =2
and c1.entity = c2.entity
and c1.value > 2 * c2.value
)
select entity, department, product, value from cte1
union
select entity, department, product, value from cte
where not exists 
( select 1 from cte1
  where cte.entity = cte1.entity
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible solution which does not make use of `CTEs`:

```
SELECT t1.Entity, t1.Department, t1.Product, t1.Value
 FROM (
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Entity, Department ORDER BY Value DESC) AS productOrder        
     FROM @T ) t1
 LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT w1.Entity, w1.Department, w1.MaxMinusDoubleOfSecondToMax
     FROM (
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Entity, Department ORDER BY Value DESC) AS productOrder,
               (MAX(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Entity, Department ORDER BY Value DESC))  - 2 * Value AS MaxMinusDoubleOfSecondToMax
     FROM @T ) w1
     WHERE w1.productOrder = 2 ) w2 ON t1.Entity = w2.Entity AND t1.Department = w2.Department
WHERE t1.productOrder = 1 OR w2.MaxMinusDoubleOfSecondToMax < 0
```

To explain the above a little bit, this nested query:

```
 SELECT w1.Entity, w1.Department, w1.MaxMinusDoubleOfSecondToMax
 FROM (
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Entity, Department ORDER BY Value DESC) AS productOrder,
           (MAX(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Entity, Department ORDER BY Value DESC))  - 2 * Value AS MaxMinusDoubleOfSecondToMax
 FROM @T ) w1
 WHERE w1.productOrder = 2
```

produces this result set:

```
Entity  Department  MaxMinusDoubleOfSecondToMax
------------------------------------------------
E1      D1          30
E2      D2          -40
```

If `MaxMinusDoubleOfSecondToMax > 0` then we need only the max record of the corresponding (Entity, Department) group, otherwise we need all records of the group.